# Json Parser error in React native

Tags: android, json, react-native

Hello I need a solution for multiple json post through react native since I'm new in React native. Here is my new json data I need to post

```
[
  {
    "rollno": "10",
    "typeofattendence": 1
  },
  {
    "rollno": "10021",
    "typeofattendence": 0
  }
]
```

Here is my fetch data please note I can  post single json data not able to post multiple.Here is my code

```
body: JSON.stringify({
        rollno: this.state.data,
        typeofattendence: this.state.value
      })`      `body: JSON.stringify({
        rollno: this.state.data,
        typeofattendence: this.state.value
      })
```

Please help me . Here you can see I can post single json object but how i post inside array multiple object . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should store your object in an array first.
For example.

```
let data = [];
data.push({
 rollno: this.state.data,
 typeofattendence: this.state.value
});
```

and when you want to send it to the server

```
body: JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: how i declare let data inside flatlist because data is in flatlist and renderitem

Comment: your code is for sending data not receiving it. renderItem is for displaying data (render the item), if you want to parse data inside renderItem, you should use JSON.parse(yourData). You can declare variable inside renderItem function or call another function inside that.

Comment: yes i want post from renderdata I get some data and want to post and data is multiple

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var myarray = [];
var myJSON = "";

var item = {
    "rollno": "10",
    "typeofattendence": 1
  };

myarray.push(item);

item = {
    "rollno": "10021",
    "typeofattendence": 0
  }
myarray.push(item);

myJSON = JSON.stringify({myarray: myarray});
```

As this http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/MWSeg/ toturial says.